# Can't find .zshrc file

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

Recently I installed someone else .dotfiles and as excepted overwrited my configuration.

The thing is that I want to use my custom settings for my ZSH but I can't find `.zshrc` inside `~/`, I have other .zshrc.files but editing none of these is working.

[image]

Also the dotfiles I've installed are in `~/.dotfiles but seems that none of these contains config.

[image]

Can someone please explain me how to edit the ZSH now, can I revert my old .zshrc?

Comment: There appears to be a symlinked `.zshrc` that appears with an appended `@` in the directory you are working in, however the dotfiles seem to have modified your tab completion which might be why you "cannot find" it. Try `ls -l ~/.zshrc` and see what path is provided to find the actual file.

Comment: thanks, its show me the original file, but even if I edit this the iterm its not updating

Comment: It will only be loaded when you launch a new terminal, so open a new tab/window to see the effects.

Comment: yes I know, I setted ZSH_THEME="honukai", I close and open and no change

Comment: Try `echo $ZSH_THEME` to see if that setting is being loaded.

Comment: yes it is, but the iterm looks the same, thats odd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110699/discussion-between-alykhank-and-hiero).

Answer (score 3):

- Go to home directory typing `cd`
- Type the command `zsh` and Press Enter
- Select the option (2)  Populate your `~/.zshrc` with the configuration
  recommended
      by the system administrator and exit (you will need to edit
      the file by hand, if so desired).

**(You have to type "2" to select it and press enter)...**

*then all the files will be created on the directory..*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating one yourself?

My Mac didn't come with the **.zshrc** file specific for my user, so I had to create one.

- Open terminal from Applications -> Utilities
- Go to your home folder by typing `cd ~`
- Type command: `touch .zshrc` and press Return

You can now open this file either from finder or terminal.

To view it on Finder:

- Open Finder and go to your Home folder
- If you are not seeing hidden files: press `COMMAND + SHIFT + .` This will help you view hidden files.

To open via Terminal:

- type `open .zshrc`

Now you can edit it and save `COMMAND+ S`

If you have added aliases to use as shortcut commands, you have to re-start your Terminal to be able to use them.